# Building your project with multiple libraries in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, hierarchy

so basically I'm trying to make this tinder swipe application. Now I've imported two libraries, AndTinder and AndTinderDemo. Now when I run the project only my mainActivity.java in AndTinderDemo runs and not my main.java in the activity i personally created. What i want to do is put the code that's in the mainactivity.java of my AndtinderDemo and put it in my main.java of my activity i created and let it run that. I have no idea how to manipulate what my Android studio should run in a hierarchy.

Now I want the code inside the AndTinderDemo mainactivity.java to be put in my main.java and I want Android studio to run the main.java and not the mainactivity.java.

This is my Manifest for my main:`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Swipe"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

`

And this is my manifest for my AndTinder:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.andtinder.demo">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="13"
    />
<application android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name="com.andtinder.demo.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: I can't post images sadly

Comment: Change Launcher activity in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Share your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: I just added the manifest

Comment: cut the intent filter and paste it under the activity you want to be as main activity in manifest.xml.

Comment: Thanks man it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You are having launcher icon for your demo library's Main activity and your activity too.

Remove `<intent-filter>` tag from the library's `<activity>` if you want to start your Activity from launcher icon.